# git: cherry-picking a newer gerrit patch

Tags: android, git

I'm working with android development, so I'm cherry-picking some commits from other gerrits.

EDIT: Here in this picture you can see what I'm talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2NCR.png (Sorry I can't post images here)

I have cherry pick into my sources patch 1 and I uploaded to my github.

Now I see they have uploaded patch 3, so:

Should I do git revert of my cherry-pick (patch 1), do a cherry pick of the newest patch and then upload it to my github?

Or is there a way to tell github that I want to overwrite with a new patch the commit I did (upgrate from patch 1 to patch 3)?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. If your patch is not in public repository (on GitHub or Gerrit) you can **rebase** it on top of team patches. If your patch is public, you can **merge** the team work (remote-tracking branch) into your work (local branch). This is Git basics.

Comment: I have re-done the question, I hope you can understand now, thanks for the help

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to **git: cherry-picking a newer gerrit patch**

Answer (score 1):

You want to get rid of **patch 1** and replace it with **patch 3**.

You first need to fetch the **patch 3** commit with **git review -d change** where **change** is the gerrit review number.

Let say **patch 1** has SHA a302c44 and **patch 3** has SHA 85050faa and you have five commits in your working branch (the one you uploaded to your github). You can now run **git rebase -i HEAD~5** and it will open an editor with something like:

```
pick 1b7585b stop.sh: only try killing processes that belong to me
pick a302c44 THIS IS PATCH 1
pick 1eb0cd5 osd: only verfy OSDMap crc if it is known
pick 3f6be22 doc: Updates man page for ceph-disk.
pick 2862a49 doc: Adds updated man page for ceph-disk under man/
```

and you manually replace **a302c44** with **85050faa** (you can ignore the comment, it won't be taken into account). Once you save and close the editor, git rebase will get rid of the patch 1 commit (because it does not show anywhere) and use the patch 3 commit instead.

Comment: But is there any other way to do the same only using cherry-picks? I will try this too, thanks

Comment: cherry-pick cannot remove a commit

Comment: Yes, but want happends if I cherry-pick patch1, and I then I chhery-pick patch3, will git overwrite patch1 with patch 3 right?